# Making home button behave similar to back button

Tags: android

I am working on an issue where my push notifications (implemented using UrbanAirship) only show up in notification center when I leave my app using the Back key. If I leave my app using the Home key, I get a ringtone/vibration to indicate that some push notification was received, but the notification does not show up in the notification area -- the notification dropdown outside of our application(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) .

I want my Home key to behave similarly to my Back key, where tapping it would actually close the application as opposed to just pausing it. From my understanding, the home button calls `onPause()` where as the back button actually calls `finish()`.

With that in mind, in my main activity, I have the following:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (MyApplication.getInstance().isApplicationSentToBackground(this)) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

My intention is to kill the activity similar to how the back button does it, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to make the home button behave similarly to the back button?

Comment: you cannot override the home button, onPause gets called for other things too not only the home button

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "push notification"? What specifically do you mean by "notification center"? "If I leave my app using the home button, I get a buzz, but the notification does not show up in the notification center" -- have you considered asking a SO question about why you are getting this behavior, showing the code relevant to it? "From my understanding, the home button calls onPause() where as the back button actually calls finish()" -- not exactly, but that is not really relevant to fixing your actual problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I'm a bit new to Android development and my terminology usage might be incorrect. I've updated my question to try to be more clear. I'll consider asking SO about why I'm getting this behavior. Thanks for your feedback